# How to force hamburger menu in Bootstrap 3.3.7 even for Desktop?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My code looks the same as this page:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar/

When I open the page in mobile, it looks like this:

[image]

But when I open it on Desktop, it looks like this:

[image]

**How can I force the page to look the same on Desktop as it does on Mobile?**

i.e. I want a hamburger menu on the desktop version of the site.

**Things I have tried**

- I set a `max-width=480px` on the outer `div` on the page, but that didn't help.
- I have also posted a related question on the softwarerecs SE (https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51989/a-css-framework-which-is-essentially-a-mobile-only-unresponsive-version-of-boo), which BTW I think is silly (libraries are intrinsic to programming and library questions should be allowed on SO!).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar):

> **Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint**
>
> The navbar collapses
> into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than
> @grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile
> view when the viewport is at least @grid-float-breakpoint in width.
> Adjust this variable in the Less source to control when the navbar
> collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or
> "tablet" screen).

you can use this [customization tool](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#grid-system) to customize the breakpoint and compile it or just edit variables.less

```
@grid-float-breakpoint:   YOUR-BREAK-POINT
```

Answer (score 6):

[Here's](https://www.bootply.com/114896#) a css-only example. Full credit to the original author.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
        <p class="navbar-text">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding-top:70px;
}

.navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
  float: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in{
  display:block !important;
}
```